# Export Diagram from Word as HighRes PNG?

Tags: microsoft-word, export, png, diagrams

I have this abysmal word document (docx) where someone put an UML diagram in (technical drawing) which is so large, that 500% zoom is not enough to read the labels on an A4 page.

Thus, I tried to export the graphic as PNG but the resulting rasterized graphic has too few pixels to read all the labels.

How to read the labels?

I can "edit image" and then alter the image so it's readable, but this is a 1000-page document which I'd rather not edit. There is also more than one diagram.

I use Word 2019.

Comment: Was the diagram created with some other software and then pasted into Word?  If so, you may be able to just copy the image and paste it into image software, where you could size it, etc., then save it.

Comment: Looks like it was created with Enterprise Architect (EA), a UML modeling tool. It's not primarily a drawing application, so I don't know how to copy and paste it back to it. I think objects in EA have some more configuration to it than just the boxes word shows.

Comment: I'm just guessing that if it could be pasted into Word, you can probably select it, copy, and paste into something like Irfanview.  Then you can do whatever you want with it (resize, cleanup, convert, save in another format).

Answer (score 1):

Do a web search on a product called **AuthorTec Save Pics** it creates picture files from objects in Word documents. It will scan the document for the object types you select and then create the files, so if there are more than one in the file, it will create pic files for all of them.

See if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found an ugly solution and I would very much appreciate an easier one.

- I copied the diagram to powerpoint, so I have a single slide with just the diagram.
- I printed the slide to PDF. The PDF is still vectorized, so I can zoom infinitely.
- I exported the PDF as a PNG using PDF X-Change Viewer (File -> Export -> as Image) where I could also set the DPI to 600 (can be freely set).

I now have an PNG with a high resolution where I can read all the labels.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a temporary new document with custom page size. (55.87 cm x
  55.87 cm Max supported)
- Ignore the print warning
- Now zoom out till you see the entire page.
- Paste your diagram here and resize it to fit the page.
- Now Right click on it and Click on Save as Picture.
- This will export it as large as page :) Hope this helps.